# How to redirect signin and signup page by react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Im new in react, I have searched but can't find any solutions. My problem is setup a personal page, if want to access home page, I must login first, there's no another option. so i use Redirect of react router to do this. I check localStorage user and redirect to /signin. But in case i haven't had any account, i must signup first. So i have a link "create account" in signin page move to signup page (/signup). and the problem is here. the redirect just allow to access /signin. i dont know how to access both pages in this case. Could have any solotion for me? Tks for reading my problem.
here is my code:
**index.js of homeTemplate**

```
  return (
    <>
      <Header />

      {props.children}
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}

const HomeTemplate = ({ exact, path, component }) => {
  if (!localStorage.getItem("KhachHang")) return <Redirect to="/signin" />;
  return (
    <LayoutHome>
      <Route exact={exact} path={path} component={component} />
    </LayoutHome>
  );
};

export default HomeTemplate;
```

app.js

````
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(LayThongTinHeThongRap());
    dispatch(LayDanhSachPhim());
  }, []);

  const showLayoutHome = (routes) => {
    if (routes && routes.length > 0) {
      return routes.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <HomeTemplate
            key={index}
            exact={item.exact}
            path={item.path}
            component={item.component}
          />
        );
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        {showLayoutHome(routeHome)}
        <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
} ```
````

Comment: If a user isn't signed in then how would you know beforehand that they don't have an account and would need to register first? Seems your `SignIn` component should provide the option to either log in and authenticate, or navigate to a "/signup" route for the user to then register.

Comment: sorry for my bad english. as you say, maybe i should  add a boolean flag to my signin component. when click on "Create account", change the flag value and with the option is signin or signup page

Comment: That could work, but I was more referring to something like this: `<Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />` where the `SignIn` component navigates to "/signup" to register a user.

Comment: I agree with Drew. You would probably be better off having a Link tag on your SignIn component that goes to the Sign Up page and let the user decide whether they need to sign up or not.